# Error activating Bean Validation Integration - Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I have been working on a project, which is a simple Spring, Hibernate, jsf,mysql integration; and I run it on Eclipse. The aim of the program is to add a Person(id, first name, last name, gender, age etc.) database on MySQLWorkbench and run it on server.I used Spring4, Hibernate4 and Eclipse Luna as tools.And I constructed the project as maven.I try to overcome different errors due to different reasons for a while.

My updated-application: https://github.com/fsel/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Eclipse-Integration

When I run it on server on Eclipse, it gives "Error activating Bean Validation Integration" error.I see it is due to "ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person".But I don't know how to solve it.

```
    Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example' did not find a matching property.
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 27 2015 12:03:56 UTC
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.61.0
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.9.5
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Library/Tomcat
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/fulden/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/fulden/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8083"]
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8011"]
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 435 ms
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 23 00:31:43 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]
ERROR: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 36 more
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 36 more
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(TypeSafeActivator.java:184)
    ... 36 more

Apr 23, 2015 12:31:45 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) for context '/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example'
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:45 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8083"]
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8011"]
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4203 ms
```

SCREEN SHOT:

[image]

domain-classes.hbm.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class table="Person" lazy="false" name="com.hibernate.data.Person">
        <id column="PERSON_ID" type="int" name="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="PERSON_FIRSTNAME" type="string" />
        <property name="lastName" column="PERSON_LASTNAME" type="string" />
        <property name="gender" column="PERSON_GENDER" type="string" />
        <property name="age" column="PERSON_AGE" type="int" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PERSONDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">fulden</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">secret_pass</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Show SQL -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Specify session context -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Autocommit -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property> 
        <!-- Referring Mapping File -->
        <mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

Problem is com.hibernate.data.Person class is not there. Do you have it, and configured as a Hibernate entity

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I'm a newbie to these kind of applications, sorry, but I don't know exactly where I should place com.hibernate.data.Person class and how to configure it.Can you please explain it?

Comment: in your hibernate.cfg.xml you need to register your class. Have a look here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm

Comment: I carefully read your link about hibernate tutorial.In my hibernate.cfg.xml, only jdbc connection pool and auto commit parts were missing.And I added them.But after running the program, I have same error again and again.Do you have any other idea about this error?

Comment: can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml and domain-clases.hbm.xml

Comment: i added both of them.

Comment: Configuration seem to be correct. But the key is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hibernate.data.Person. For some reason sprig cannot find the Person class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is right, but based on your screen shot I would make sure you have your project configured correctly in Eclipse. The 'java' folder underneath the 'src' folder should be a java source folder (but it's rendered as a file resource). Check your project settings and make sure its part of the build path. If it's not, then it won't be picked up when your .war file is generated.

Comment: Before beginning the project, I have first created it as "Dynamic Web Project" and then converted it to Maven project.I suppose, maybe, the error might be due to that.

Comment: You need to right click on the project folder and then click 'properties'. Then click on the 'Java Build Path' node and verify your 'java' folder is one of the 'sources'. Have a look here: [Screen Shot](http://i.imgur.com/Yr5kyjj.png)

Comment: I added updated structure of the project and the screen shot you wanted me to check.It seems that I have an error "Build path entry is missing: Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example/src/test/java".Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Try to modify the entry that is giving you the problem.